# Still getting "NameError: name 'python' is not defined" in the console even after adding PATH and ENV

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I can't figure out why Sublime Text 3's console can't reach any PATH commands. `python` and `coffee` return "is not defined" errors. I've tried a bunch of different things:

I've added a `Python.sublime-settings` to Packages/Python and I've been trying to get the right paths

```
{

  "env" :
 {
"PYTHONPATH" : "/usr/local/bin/python:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/lib/python:/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
//"PYTHONPATH" : "/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/python:/Users/zak/.nvm/v0.10.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/zak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/zak/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/local/bin"
 },

  "path": "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin/python:/usr/local/bin/python:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/lib/python",
 // "cmd": ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
"cmd": ["python", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
}
```

I've also tried adding a `path.py` to `Packages/User`:

import os

```
LOCAL = '/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/python:/Users/zak/.nvm/v0.10.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global/bin:/Users/zak/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin:/Users/zak/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/local/bin'


os.environ['PATH'] += ':'
os.environ['PATH'] += LOCAL

# print('PATH = ' + os.environ['PATH'])
```

Nothing works. Not only can't I use `python` and `coffee` from the console, but my installed packages that use those libraries are failing as well. How can I get Sublime Text 3 to use a correct PATH and environmental variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only valid keys for the `.sublime-settings` file are those in the default settings. I don't think there is an `env` or `path` key. In addition, the ST console is not a terminal console. It's a python shell. In addition, ST uses a bundled version of Python. You may be able to modify that, I'm not sure. Terminal integration is something that many users would like to have, but it isn't implemented yet.

From what you put, it looks like you are trying to create a new build file. These files have a `.sublime-build` extension. More information about build systems can be found [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems.html).

Hope that helps clarify some things about why it isn't working.